# linewidth failed after using \dim_set_eq in LaTeX3

Tags: expl3, latex3

When I wanted to compare a dimension variable with the current linewidth, I use the follow MWE code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_new:N \l_line_width_dim
\dim_set_eq:NN \l_line_width_dim \linewidth
\ExplSyntaxOff
\linewidth
\end{document}
```

But I found that after using `\dim_set_eq`, `\linewidth` and `\textwidth` failed, and the message was

```
Missing number,treated as zero.
```

and

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: `\linewidth` has no fixed value: it will be reset in various occasions. Maybe you want `\columnwidth`? Anyway, the error does not depend on any added code, in particular `\dim_set_eq:NN`. If you want to print the current value, you need `\the\linewidth`.

Comment: Your issue is not related to `\dim_set_eq`, you get the same error if you remove the entire `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff` block. You can't use `\linewidth` on it's own. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I remembered to use `\linewidth` directly, maybe I didn't use it very often, so I made a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the code from `\ExplSyntaxOn` to `\ExplSyntaxOff`, you get the same error.

This is because `\linewidth` is the name of a length register; you can use it alone when TeX is expecting a length, for instance in

```
\setlength{\mylength}{0.5\linewidth}
```

or

```
\parbox{\linewidth}{...}
```

Of course also in

```
\dim_set_eq:NN \l_line_width_dim \linewidth
```

because a length register is expected.

If used out of context, the syntax rules of TeX make it into thinking that you want to *assign a value* to `\linewidth`, hence the error message that a number is missing.

If you want to *print* the current value of `\linewidth`, you need

```
\the\linewidth
```

Comment: Thanks so so much, you explained it very clearly.